# Cleaning `Inf` values from an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

In R, I have an operation which creates some `Inf` values when I transform a dataframe.

I would like to turn these `Inf` values into `NA` values.  The code I have is slow for large data, is there a faster way of doing this?

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1, Inf), b=c(Inf, 3), d=c("a","b"))
```

The following works in a single case:

```
 dat[,1][is.infinite(dat[,1])] = NA
```

So I generalized it with following loop

```
cf_DFinf2NA <- function(x)
{
    for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
          x[,i][is.infinite(x[,i])] = NA
    }
    return(x)
}
```

But I don't think that this is really using the power of R.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

### Option 1

Use the fact that a `data.frame` is a list of columns, then use `do.call` to recreate a `data.frame`.

```
do.call(data.frame,lapply(DT, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x),NA)))
```

### Option 2 -- `data.table`

You could use `data.table` and `set`. This avoids some internal copying.

```
DT <- data.table(dat)
invisible(lapply(names(DT),function(.name) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[.name]])), j = .name,value =NA)))
```

Or using column numbers (possibly faster if there are a lot of columns):

```
for (j in 1:ncol(DT)) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[j]])), j, NA)
```

## Timings

```
# some `big(ish)` data
dat <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6), b = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6), 
                  c = rep(c('a','b'),1e6),d = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6),  
                  e = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6))
# create data.table
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)

# replace (@mnel)
system.time(na_dat <- do.call(data.frame,lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x),NA))))
## user  system elapsed 
#  0.52    0.01    0.53 

# is.na (@dwin)
system.time(is.na(dat) <- sapply(dat, is.infinite))
# user  system elapsed 
# 32.96    0.07   33.12 

# modified is.na
system.time(is.na(dat) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(dat, is.infinite)))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.22    0.38    1.60 


# data.table (@mnel)
system.time(invisible(lapply(names(DT),function(.name) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[.name]])), j = .name,value =NA))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.29    0.02    0.31
```

`data.table` is the quickest. Using `sapply` slows things down noticeably.

Comment: Great work on the timings and the modification @mnel. I wish there were an SO way to transfer rep across accounts. I think I will go out and upvotes some other answers of yours.

Comment: error in do.call(train, lapply(train, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x),  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function

Comment: If you are happy to replace in situ then the following simplification will work: dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x),NA))

Answer (score 66):

Use `sapply` and `is.na<-`

```
> dat <- data.frame(a=c(1, Inf), b=c(Inf, 3), d=c("a","b"))
> is.na(dat) <- sapply(dat, is.infinite)
> dat
   a  b d
1  1 NA a
2 NA  3 b
```

Or you can use (giving credit to @mnel, whose edit this is),

```
> is.na(dat) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(dat, is.infinite))
```

which is significantly faster.

Comment: The "trick" was in realizing the `is.na<-` would not accept a result from `lapply` but would accept one from `sapply`.

Comment: I've added some timings. I'm not sure why the `is.na<-` solution is so much slower.

Comment: a bit of profiling, and I've edited your solution to be much faster.

Comment: this is the best and most elegant solution, Well done @IRTFM

Answer (score 29):

Here is a dplyr/tidyverse solution using the [na_if() function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html):

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., Inf)))
```

Note that this only replaces positive infinity with NA. Need to repeat if negative infinity values also need to be replaced.

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., Inf))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., -Inf)))
```

Comment: With the new `across` function, this can now be down in a single `mutate` call:

`mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~na_if(., Inf)), across(where(is.numeric), ~na_if(., -Inf)))`

Answer (score 19):

`[<-` with `mapply` is a bit faster than `sapply`.

```
> dat[mapply(is.infinite, dat)] <- NA
```

With mnel's data, the timing is

```
> system.time(dat[mapply(is.infinite, dat)] <- NA)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 15.281   0.000  13.750
```

Answer (score 8):

There is very simple solution to this problem in the hablar package:

```
library(hablar)

dat %>% rationalize()
```

Which return a data frame with all Inf are converted to NA.

Timings compared to some above solutions. Code:
library(hablar)
library(data.table)

```
dat <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6), b = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6), 
                  c = rep(c('a','b'),1e6),d = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6),  
                  e = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6))
DT <- data.table(dat)

system.time(dat[mapply(is.infinite, dat)] <- NA)
system.time(dat[dat==Inf] <- NA)
system.time(invisible(lapply(names(DT),function(.name) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[.name]])), j = .name,value =NA))))
system.time(rationalize(dat))
```

Result:

```
> system.time(dat[mapply(is.infinite, dat)] <- NA)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.125   0.039   0.164 
> system.time(dat[dat==Inf] <- NA)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.095   0.010   0.108 
> system.time(invisible(lapply(names(DT),function(.name) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[.name]])), j = .name,value =NA))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.065   0.002   0.067 
> system.time(rationalize(dat))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.058   0.014   0.072 
>
```

Seems like data.table is faster than hablar. But has longer syntax.

Comment: Timings please?

Comment: @ricardo added some timings

Answer (score 3):

Feng Mai has a tidyverse answer above to get negative and positive infinities:

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., Inf))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., -Inf)))
```

This works well, but a word of warning is not to swap in abs(.) here to do both lines at once as is proposed in an upvoted comment.  It will look like it works, but changes all negative values in the dataset to positive!  You can confirm with this:

```
data(iris)
#The last line here is bad - it converts all negative values to positive
iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~scale(.)) %>%
  mutate(infinities = Sepal.Length / 0) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(abs(.), Inf)))
```

For one line, this works:

```
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(abs(.) == Inf,NA,.))
```

Comment: Good catch! I've added a comment to this affect on the original comment--I think that's a better place to address the issue than a new answer. Also found some posts of yours worthy of upvotes to get you a little closer to the 50 reputation required to comment anywhere.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I would have left a comment if I'd been able.

Comment: do you know why it doesnt work with if_else instead of ifelse in the last code?

Answer (score 2):

Inside a dplyr pipe chain, you can do this.

```
%>% mutate_all(.,.funs = function(x){ifelse(is.infinite(x),NA,x)}) %>%
```

I find it simple, elegant and fast.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers already, but would like to add that for me this `tidyverse` solution always worked well:

```
%>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x) | is.infinite(x), NA, x)) %>%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
    dat <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6), b = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6), 
                      c = rep(c('a','b'),1e6),d = rep(c(1,Inf), 1e6),  
                      e = rep(c(Inf,2), 1e6))
    system.time(dat[dat==Inf] <- NA)

#   user  system elapsed
#  0.316   0.024   0.340
```

Comment: MusTheDataGuy, why would you edit my answer but not add your own solution? There is already "add another answer" button!

Answer (score 0):

Also, if someone need the Infs' coordinates, can do this:

```
library(rlist)
list.clean(apply(df, 2, function(x){which(is.infinite(x))}), function(x) length(x) == 0L, TRUE)
```

Result:

```
$colname1
[1] row1 row2 ...
$colname2
[2] row1 row2 ...
```

With this information, you can replace the Inf values in particular places with the mean, median, or whatever operator that you want.

For example (for element 01):

```
repInf = list.clean(apply(df, 2, function(x){which(is.infinite(x))}), function(x) length(x) == 0L, TRUE)
df[repInf[[1]], names(repInf)[[1]]] = median or mean(is.finite(df[ ,names(repInf)[[1]]]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

In loop:

```
for (nonInf in 1:length(repInf)) {
df[repInf[[nonInf]], names(repInf)[[nonInf]]] = mean(is.finite(df[ , names(repInf)[[nonInf]]]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in, thought this worked well.

```
infNanReplace <- function (v, r = 0) {
  v[!is.finite(v)] <- r
  return(v)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also use the handy replace_na function:
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.