# Replace Inf in R data.table / Show number of Inf in colums

Tags: r, data.table, infinite, na

I can't figure out how to use an is.na(x) like function for infinite numbers in R with a data table or show per column how many Inf's there are: colSums(is.infinite(x))

I use the following example data set:

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1/0,1,2/0),b=c("a","b","c"),c=c(1/0,5,NA))
DT
     a b   c
1: Inf a Inf
2:   1 b   5
3: Inf c   NA
colSums(is.na(DT))
a b c 
0 0 1 
colSums(is.infinite(DT))
Error in is.infinite(DT) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
DT[is.na(DT)] <- 100
 DT
     a b   c
1: Inf a Inf
2:   1 b   5
3: Inf c 100

DT[is.infinite(DT)] <- 100
Error in is.infinite(DT) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188509/cleaning-inf-values-from-an-r-dataframe) how to replace Inf with NA, but I would say there should be nicer way of achieving this, with is.infinite for example. And I would like to see the Inf's per column, any ideas about this?

Many thanks.
BR Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is.finite` and `is.infinite` don't have a `data.frame` or a `data.table` methods like `is.na` has (compare `methods(is.infinite)` vs `methods(is.na)`)

You could alternatively loop thru the columns and then use `colSums`

```
DT[, colSums(sapply(.SD, is.infinite))]
# a b c 
# 2 0 1
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `Reduce` instead of `colSums`

```
DT[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.infinite))]
## [1] 2 0 1
```

---

Another option is to create your own custom function and then just loop it over the columns

```
Myfunc <- function(x) sum(is.infinite(x))
DT[, lapply(.SD, Myfunc)]
#    a b c
# 1: 2 0 1
```

Of course you could also write `data.frame` method for `is.infinite` as it appears to be generic (see `?is.infinite`).

Comment: Also, `colSums(DT=='Inf', na.rm=TRUE)` would work, though not elegant

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I always forget this works too, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: The quote is not needed though, I think it must work in the same way as DT==1 or other value

Comment: @akrun it still looks somewhat fishy to me. The documentation clearly says "*do not test equality to NaN*", though it doesn't mention anything regarding `Inf`

Comment: @akrun, @Frank just pointed out that we need to cover `-Inf` too. Completely slipped my mind

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg and @akrun! What is your preferred solution to replace Inf with NA? I found the method in the link I provided in the question not so elegant...

Comment: I think the one from the previous post is not that ugly though.. : `for (j in 1:ncol(DT)) set(DT, which(is.infinite(DT[[j]])), j, NA)`

Comment: The `set` method is very efficient, but is hard to read. If your data set no too bug, i would go with a simple `replace`. For example: create a custom function `Myfunc <- function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x), NA)`, then simply loop it over the columns and update by reference `DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, Myfunc)]`