# dplyr rowwise by some columns

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

What is the **dplyr** way to apply a function `rowwise` for some columns.  For example I want to Grab all the `V,` columns and turn them into percents based on the row sums.  I show how to do it in base.  What about in a **dplyr** chain.  It'd nice to see in **data.table** form as well (though preference would go to a **dplyr** solution here).

```
x <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:5], as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 25, T), ncol=5)))

data.frame(x[1], x[-1]/rowSums(x[-1]))


##   A        V1        V2        V3         V4         V5
## 1 A 0.1428571 0.2142857 0.2142857 0.35714286 0.07142857
## 2 B 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.1500000 0.20000000 0.25000000
## 3 C 0.3571429 0.2857143 0.0000000 0.07142857 0.28571429
## 4 D 0.1904762 0.2380952 0.1904762 0.23809524 0.14285714
## 5 E 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.1500000 0.25000000 0.15000000

library(dplyr)

props <- function(x) round(x/sum(x), 2)

# does not work
x %>%
    rowwise()
    mutate(props(matches("^.{2}$")))
```

Comment: Maybe `x %>% rowwise() %>% select(matches("^.{2}$")) %>% props %>% cbind(x[1], .)`?  The second half isn't really dplyrey though

Comment: I'm not a dplyr expert, but can't you just use `rowSums` in dplyr too? Something like `props <- function(x, y) round(x/y, 2) ; x %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% mutate_each(funs(./Total), -c(A, Total))`. Though both `rowSums` and `rowwise` should be inefficient. I would go with ```Reduce(`+`, .[-1]))``` instead, if you don't have `NA`s.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice can you throw down as an answer.  It works.

Comment: Tyler, did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354734/dplyr-mutate-rowsums-calculations-or-custom-functions)? I wonder if you want some general row wise solution or specifically sum by row?

Comment: @Frank true no need.  I'll remove, though it sould allow anyone to just run the code with no need to type library etc. to get dplyr.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I hadn't seen that but what you demo-ed is exactly what I was after. Funny it comes from a known data.table guy.

Comment: A "known data.table guy" who is near hadley in the SO dplyr answers leaderboard :) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dplyr/topusers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr)'s `spread` and `gather` with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to get the following single pipeline:

```
x <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:5], as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 25, T), ncol=5)))

y <- x %>% 
        gather(V, val, -A) %>% 
        group_by(A) %>% 
        mutate(perc = val / sum(val)) %>% 
        select(-val) %>%
        spread(V, perc)
```

With [**tidy data**](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) it's quite easy to get any group-wise sum (rows, columns or any nested index-level) and compute percentages. The `spread` and `gather` will get you to and from your input data format.

Comment: Ahh makes perfect sense.  This is a "why didn't I think of that moment".

Comment: doing a by-row grouping like this, my guess is this will slow down quickly as data grows

Comment: @eddi I haven't tested this on big data. dplyr probably isn't  the best way for that any way. I doubt that it would be slower than the `data.frame` rescaling by `rowSums` that the OP showed. In the tidy data format, one could always do an `arrange(A)` before doing the `group_by(A)`, so that the data per group is sequentially processed.

Answer (score 7):

In data.table, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

x[, grep("^V",names(DT)) := .SD/Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = V1:V5]

   A         V1        V2        V3         V4         V5
1: A 0.28571429 0.0000000 0.2857143 0.07142857 0.35714286
2: B 0.23076923 0.2307692 0.3076923 0.15384615 0.07692308
3: C 0.44444444 0.0000000 0.4444444 0.00000000 0.11111111
4: D 0.07142857 0.3571429 0.1428571 0.07142857 0.35714286
5: E 0.00000000 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.44444444 0.00000000
```

To compute the denominator with NA values ignored, I guess `rowSums` is an option, though it will coerce `.SD` to a matrix as an intermediate step.

Comment: It''s fine. I didn't invent ```Reduce(`+`,...```. I'm just wondering if this isn't a dupe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306500/r-data-table-count-na-per-row/35306944 is relevant, though not exactly the same.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Seems it should be a dupe but I couldn't find one with an obvious title.

Comment: @thelatemail We are doing these ```Reduce(`+`, .SD)``` for [some time now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353894/replace-inf-in-r-data-table-show-number-of-inf-in-colums/30354129#30354129). Here's akrun [in 2014](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305233/how-can-i-specify-columns-in-r-to-be-used-in-matches-without-listing-each-indiv/26305482#26305482)

Comment: Didn't realize you could pass column numbers on LHS of `:=`... I would have used `value = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Another "tidyverse" solution is to use a `select`  within a `mutate`. E.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:5], as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 25, T), ncol=5)))

x %>% 
  mutate(row_counts = select_if(., is.numeric) %>% rowSums()) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("V")), funs(./row_counts)) %>% 
  select(-row_counts)
#>   A        V1         V2        V3        V4        V5
#> 1 A 0.0000000 0.14285714 0.1428571 0.5714286 0.1428571
#> 2 B 0.0000000 0.62500000 0.1250000 0.1250000 0.1250000
#> 3 C 0.2222222 0.11111111 0.2222222 0.1111111 0.3333333
#> 4 D 0.3000000 0.50000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.0000000
#> 5 E 0.3333333 0.06666667 0.1333333 0.3333333 0.1333333
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>