# Distinguishing between infinity and negative infinity during value replacement in R

Tags: r, infinity

There are some good examples of how to replace infinite values in R with NA in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188509/cleaning-inf-values-from-an-r-dataframe).

For instance,

```
DT <- data.table(dat)
invisible(lapply(names(DT),function(.name) set(DT, 
           which(is.infinite(DT[[.name]])), j = .name,value =NA)))
```

However, this doesn't distinguish between positive (`Inf`) and negative infinity (`-Inf`).

I need to make this distinction because instead of just replacing the values with `NA` and throwing them out or imputing them, I'd like to try using the max non-infinite value for positive infinity and min non-infinity value for negative infinity (and things like that).

Is this possible?

***Example input data***

`a <- c(-1,2,3,4,100/0,-100/0)`

`[1]    -1    2    3    4  Inf -Inf`

***Example output data***

`[1] -1  1  2  3  4  4 -1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just combine `is.infinite` with a standard `>` or `<` comparison?

```
a <- c(-1,2,3,4,100/0,-100/0)

a[is.infinite(a) & a < 0] <- min(a[!is.infinite(a)])
a[is.infinite(a) & a > 0] <- max(a[!is.infinite(a)])
a
[1] -1  2  3  4  4 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may extract/replace any -Inf or Inf values in your vector in an even simpler fashion:

```
a <- c(-1,2,3,4,100/0,-100/0)   

a[a <= -Inf] <- min(a[is.finite(a)])    
a[a >= Inf] <- max(a[is.finite(a)])  

a
[1] -1  2  3  4  4 -1
```

Comment: why not just `a == -Inf`?