# Replace infinite values in an R data frame [why doesn't `is.infinite()` behave like `is.na()`]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
             col2 = c(NA, Inf, 5))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A        NA
#> 2 B       Inf
#> 3 C         5
```

I can use the base R `is.na()` function to easily replace `NA`s with `0`s, shown below:

```
df %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         0
#> 2 B       Inf
#> 3 C         5
```

If I try to duplicate this logic with `is.infinite()` things break:

```
df %>% replace(is.infinite(.), 1)
#> Error in is.infinite(.) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Looking at this [older answer about Inf and R data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188509/cleaning-inf-values-from-an-r-dataframe) I can hack together the solution shown below. This takes my original data frame and turns all `NA` into `0` and all `Inf` into `1`. Why doesn't `is.infinite()` behave like `is.na()` and what is *(perhaps)* a better way to do what I want?

```
df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(abs(.), Inf))) %>%  # line 3
  replace(is.na(.), 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         0
#> 2 B         1
#> 3 C         5
```

Comment: If you check `?is.infinite` - `x - R object to be tested: the default methods handle atomic vectors.` where `?is.na` have methods for `matrix/data.frame/vector`. i.e. `x - an R object to be tested: the default method for is.na and anyNA handle atomic vectors, lists, pairlists, and NULL`.

Comment: You can try `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ replace(., is.infinite(.), 1))`

Comment: You could do `df %>% replace(sapply(., is.infinite), 1)`

Comment: Thanks, slight correction though, it'd be this; `df %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% replace(sapply(., is.infinite), 1)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `is.infinite` expects the input 'x' to be atomic vector according to `?is.infinite`

> x-  object to be tested: the default methods handle atomic vectors.

whereas `?is.na` can take a vector, matrix, data.frame as input

> an R object to be tested: the default method for is.na and anyNA handle atomic vectors, lists, pairlists, and NULL

Also, by checking the `methods`,

```
methods('is.na')
#[1] is.na.data.frame      is.na.data.table*     is.na.numeric_version is.na.POSIXlt         is.na.raster*         is.na.vctrs_vctr*    

methods('is.infinite') # only for vectors
#[1] is.infinite.vctrs_vctr*
```

---

We can modify the `replace` in the code to

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ replace_na(., 0) %>% 
                             replace(., is.infinite(.), 1))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  col1   col2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A         0
#2 B         1
#3 C         5
```