# find maximum value for multiple rows on condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, max, aggregate

I have troubles with the following problem. I need to keep track of the maximum value of `crp` and `gluc` for each `ID` in the 3 hours before and after each measurement in a series. I tried different solutions over the last few months and was not able to solve this. I have a dataset like the one below:

```
ID  crp gluc hour
1   5   300  0.3
1   2   NA   0.9
1   NA  89   1.2
1   9   NA   4
1   NA  100  7.1
2   0   NA   0.3
2   NA  50   1
2   NA  70   2.2
2   1   80   5
```

The result should be:

```
ID  crp gluc hours  maxCrp  MaxGluc
1   5   300  0.3    5       300
1   2   NA   0.9    5       300
1   NA  89   1.2    9       300
1   9   NA   4      9       89
1   NA  100  7.1    NA      100
2   0   NA   0.3    0       70
2   NA  50   1      0       70
2   NA  70   2.2    1       80
2   1   80   5      1       80
```

Thank you in advance,
Erik

Comment: Welcome on board. Please revise your question as there is no 3 hours subset!. Also, please check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tempting, and generally useful, to use a cool R tool like `mutate` for this, but since your problem is very specific I prefer using for loops with clear statements that implement each part of your requirement.
Here's how I would go:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),crp=c(5,2,NA,9,NA,0,NA,NA,1),gluc=c(300,NA,89,NA,100,NA,50,70,80),hour=c(0.3,0.9,1.2,4,7.1,.3,1,2.2,5)) 
df1$maxCrp <- 0
df1$MaxGluc <- 0
clinical_window <- 3
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  mask <- (df1$ID == df1$ID[i]) & (abs(df1$hour-df1$hour[i]) < clinical_window)
  df1$maxCrp[i] <- max(df1$crp[mask], na.rm=TRUE)
  df1$MaxGluc[i] <- max(df1$gluc[mask], na.rm=TRUE)
}
df1$maxCrp[is.infinite(df1$maxCrp)] <- NA
df1$MaxGluc[is.infinite(df1$MaxGluc)] <- NA
```

This code will throw a warning, as it should, where there is missing data.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you very much. Your code works like a charm. Best regards, Erik

Comment: @E.K., please accept the answer if it's the best one :-)

Answer (score 0):

If interested, you could use `data.table` and the following approach.

This includes a non-equi self-join, including `max` values for `crp` and `gluc` based on values for `hour` that fall between +/- 3 hours.

The `tmp` temporary data.table with the `max` results are joined back to the original data.

The last line with `lapply` is [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188551/3460670) as one way to remove infinite values from a data table.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

tmp <- dt[dt[, .(ID, hour, lower = hour - 3, upper = hour + 3)]
   , on = .(ID = ID, hour >= lower, hour <= upper)
   , .(ID, hour, crp, gluc)
   , allow.cartesian = TRUE
][, .(maxCrp = max(crp, na.rm = T), maxGluc = max(gluc, na.rm = T))
  , by = .(ID, hour)]

dt <- dt[tmp, on = .(ID, hour)]

invisible(lapply(names(dt), 
                 function(.name) set(dt, which(is.infinite(dt[[.name]])), 
                                     j = .name, value = NA)))

dt
```

**Output**

```
   ID crp gluc hour maxCrp maxGluc
1:  1   5  300  0.3      5     300
2:  1   2   NA  0.9      5     300
3:  1  NA   89  1.2      9     300
4:  1   9   NA  4.0      9      89
5:  1  NA  100  7.1     NA     100
6:  2   0   NA  0.3      0      70
7:  2  NA   50  1.0      0      70
8:  2  NA   70  2.2      1      80
9:  2   1   80  5.0      1      80
```